# Delay loading payments methods for purchase orders?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

When you are a purchaser and have an approved order and click on place order it will take you to the checkout to confirm the payment. However, we use adyen for the credit card payment option and this one always fails to load correctly on first load, so when the customer clicks on "place order" from the account page and goes to checkout (payment) for the first time. On page refresh it then works correctly. How can we delay the payment methods to load in order for it to work on first load as well?

Comment: Do you have any error on the first load, either in the brower console, or in the logs ?